# snaplogic - from single record to multiple rows in csv

Tags: xml, csv, parsing, snaplogic

How I can build a pipeline that gets a input as below and then needs to split this into 2 records in CSV file as in the image?

```html
<HOU>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <HOU SEGMENT="1">
      <ACTIVE>Yes</ACTIVE>
      <NAME>Scraper Equipment</NAME>
      <TYPE>Rental</TYPE>
      <REF>22-367817</REF>
      <SER_NUM>348-2326</SER_NUM>
    </HOU>
  </IDOC>
</HOU>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can have each individual row mapping sandwiched between a Copy snap and a Union snap.

Following is a sample pipeline.

[image]

Parsed sample XML:

[image]

Mapping corresponding to row #1.

[image]

Mapping corresponding to row #2.

[image]

Result of the union.

[image]